# How to disable button before combobox data is selected in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a simple template that includes a combobox, a button and a table.
What i want to do is, buttons are not clickable if combobox value is not selected, and after selected this button will call a service method, get employer details and the table become visible after this.(table will not be visible before combobox value selected and button is clicked.)
My code is:

```
 <mat-card-content fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="left" fxLayoutGap="30px">

          <mat-form-field fxFlex="30%">
            <mat-select placeholder="Choose Employer"
                        [(ngModel)]="customModel"
                        #activeEmployers="ngModel"
                        required>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let emp of employerList" [value]="emp.displayName">{{emp.displayName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button type="button" class="get-button" (click)="getEmployers()">
            GET DETAILS
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>

      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-content>
          <mat-table #table [dataSource]="employerList">
            <!-- table rows -->

            <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row class="table-row" *cdkRowDef="let config; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

          </mat-table>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
```

this template is working but static, all components are visible default. How can i make that functionality that I have mentioned above.

note: all these elements are in same component in ts file. So there is no child-parent relation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

In your select-element use the `change`-directive. If a change happens the method `onSelection()` gets fired. The method sets the boolean `selectionFired` to `true`.
If this happens the button gets enabled. `[disabled]="!selectionFired"`

If you click the button the boolean `buttonClicked` is set to true and this lets the table appear. `*ngIf="buttonClicked"`

```
<mat-card-content fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="left" fxLayoutGap="30px">

      <mat-form-field fxFlex="30%">
        <mat-select placeholder="Choose Employer"
                    [(ngModel)]="customModel"
                    #activeEmployers="ngModel"
                    (change)="onSelection()"
                    required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let emp of employerList" [value]="emp.displayName">{{emp.displayName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button type="button" class="get-button" [disabled]="!selectionFired" (click)="getEmployers()">
        GET DETAILS
      </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>

  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-table *ngIf="buttonClicked" #table [dataSource]="employerList">
        <!-- table rows -->

        <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row class="table-row" *cdkRowDef="let config; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

      </mat-table>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

And in your TypeScript-File

```
  protected selectionFired: boolean = false;
  protected buttonClicked: boolean = false;

  protected onSelection(): void {
      this.selectionFired = true;
  }

  protected getEmployers(): void {
      this.buttonClicked = true;
  }
```